# How to dynamically create UPDATE query in SQL, where columns are different per call?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a data payload that comes in `JSON` format which dictates what I will be updating in said table. I am using a `PreparedStatement`. I am using `Java v8.212`. I am on `MySQL`. I only want to update the fields that come in the payload:

**payload**

```
{
 "column1": "value1"
 "column2": "value2"...
}
```

I loop through said payload and create my `SQL` statement like so:

```
String sql = "UPDATE table SET\n";

if(payload.valueX.isPresent) {
  //i have something at the end of the method that deals with commas
  sql.append("columnX = " + payload.getColumnX;
}

if(thisOtherColumnExists..) { etc }

try (Connection conn = geConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
  //at this point how do i dynamically set bound vars?
  ps.executeQuery();
}
```

I do not like this format because there is a possibility of an `SQL` injection attack. **How do I create it with bound variables:**

```
if(payload.valueX.isPresent) {
  sql.append("columnX = ?";
}

//how to dynamically set?
preparedStatement.setString();
```

**then loop through the SQL and add the proper values to the proper field?** Sometimes I will be updating five columns, sometimes ten, sometimes one, and they will almost always not be in the same order.

Comment: If you have a fixed set of columns, of which your update is a subset, you can create the full set of parameters, set the unused ones to null, and use the format `set column1=isnull(@param1,column1)` in your update.

Answer (score -1):

You have to search prepared statements with multiple parameters.

Basically you can give an order to setString method.

```
if(payload.valueX.isPresent) {
  sql.append("columnX = ?";
  preparedStatement.setString(1,payload.getColumnX;);
}

 //adding an integer parameter, e.g
if(payload.valueY.isPresent) {
  sql.append("columnY = ?";
  preparedStatement.setInt(2,payload.getColumnY;);
}
```

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) can help you with examples :

If you want a more dynamic approach for ordering statements, I think you have to set a loop variable and increment that variable whenever you append new item.

> Edit after the change of the question

What you have to do use a collection (Array/List/HashMap etc) and populate with each sql condition.
In the try/catch loop this collection and add prepared statements simultaneously.

**Note :** Please don't edit an accepted answer, since your edited question also requires changes in answer so we can not continue like that always editing. :)

Comment: now that i think about it some more.. how can you set the value if you already have an open statement? updated my question..